# Ruby on Rails Iphone development

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails

I've been digging around for this one. I understand that there two possible ways to develop for the iPhone.

1. via web kit frameworks, such as jqtouch and iwebkit, and
2. using the iPhone's api

I notice quite a few people using web kit frameworks, especially jqtouch. What are the benefits of using a webkit framework versus using the iPhone's api directly?

One point that springs into mind, is the fact that using a web kit framework makes it accessible through other smart phones? Not just the iPhone?

Are there any differences in terms of graphic enhancements? i.e. will transitions or animation look different?

I am a web developer by heart. It will be an advantage if I can develop an iPhone app with knowledge that I already know, that being the Ruby on Rails web framework.

I have also read this [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/akosma/webtuesday-mobile-web-applications-framework-overview), which seems pretty detailed on various web kits.

Your suggestions / feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came across the following by [Oreilly](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/ch01.html#ch01_id35816684) which seems to answer a good detail of differences between a native and web app development for the iPhone.